# Flash Cs4 components skinning / themes?

Tags: flash, components, themes, edit, skin

is there a way to apply custom skin / theme on components in flash Cs4.

I remembeer I could edit them in flash 8 as2, but in flash cs4 they just an objects. 
without option to edit "content" of them.

Answer (score 0):

If you just double-click on the instance of the button on the stage you can jump right in and skin it!